# Will a CAN Bus network with 2 Arduino / MCP2515 nodes work?

Tags: networking, arduino, can-bus

I'd like to set up a CAN network of multiple nodes using Arduino Pro Minis and MCP2515 cards. But I can't get the Receive to work.

```cpp
#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <SPI.h>

long unsigned int  rxId;
unsigned char      len = 0;
unsigned char      rxBuf[8];
char               msgString[128];
#define  CAN0_INT  2                    // Set INT to pin 2
MCP_CAN            CAN0(10);            // Set CS to pin 10

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);       
    //  Initialize MCP2515 running at 8MHz with a baudrate of 125kb/s
    //  and the masks and filters disabled.
    while (CAN_OK != CAN0.begin(MCP_ANY, CAN_125KBPS, MCP_8MHZ)) {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS Module Failed to Initialize.");
    } 
    Serial.println("MCP2515 Initialized Successfully!");
    CAN0.setMode(MCP_NORMAL);
    pinMode(CAN0_INT, INPUT);        // Configuring pin for /INT input
}

void loop() {
    if(!digitalRead(CAN0_INT)) {  // If CAN0_INT is low, read receive buffer
        CAN0.readMsgBuf(&rxId, &len, rxBuf);   // Read data: len = data length, buf = data byte(s)

        if((rxId & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000)  // Is ID standard (11 bits) or extended (29 bits)?
            sprintf(msgString, "Extended ID: 0x%.8lX  DLC: %1d  Data:", (rxId & 0x1FFFFFFF), len);
        else
            sprintf(msgString, "Standard ID: 0x%.3lX   DLC: %1d  Data:", rxId, len);
        Serial.print(msgString);

        if((rxId & 0x40000000) == 0x40000000) {    // Is message a remote request frame?
            sprintf(msgString, " REMOTE REQUEST FRAME");
            Serial.print(msgString);
        } else {
            for(byte i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                sprintf(msgString, " 0x%.2X", rxBuf[i]);
                Serial.print(msgString);
            }
        }        
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

However, all I get out are the error messages, including this:

```
Entering Configuration Mode Failure
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by, "CAN network?" The common usage means Campus Area Network, although I have heard it mean Controlled Access Network, but that doesn't seem to make sense with your question.

Comment: "From Wikipedia, the Controller Area Network (CAN) bus is a 'vehicle bus standard designed to allow microcontrollers and devices to communicate with each other within a vehicle without a host computer.' These devices can also be referred to as electronic control units (ECUs). Essentially the CAN bus is a bunch of linked ECUs within the vehicle that communicate with each based on a broadcast. Every ECU intercepts every broadcast, but individually decide whether or not to react to it."   (http://www.instructables.com/id/CAN-Bus-Sniffing-and-Broadcasting-with-Arduino/)

Comment: OK. My point is that you need to be more specific when there are multiple meanings. You should edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I got the circuit to work. The 2-node CAN Bus is communicating.
I found this [site](https://www.engineersgarage.com/contribution/getting-started-can-interface-arduino) and made a couple of changes:

1. My Arduino ProMini MISI, MISO pins were not aligned with the SI, SO pins on the MCP2515s.
2. I used the CAN_BUS_Shield library.